# How to handle both: onClick and onMouseMove for one dom element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const LONG_CLICK_TOLERANCE_MS = 250;
const HEIGHT_TOLERANCE = 45;

const getCurrentTimeMS = () => {
    return (new Date()).getTime();
};

const getClientY = (e) => {
    if (e.clientY !== undefined) {
        return e.clientY;
    }
    return e.touches[0].clientY;
};

const getDefaultMouseMove = () => {
    return {
        startedAtMS: null,
        y: null,
        initialHeight: null,
    };
};


    handleMoveStart = e => {
        this.mouseMove = {
            startedAtMS: getCurrentTimeMS(),
            y: getClientY(e),
            initialHeight: this.state.height,
        };
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMoveProcess);
        document.addEventListener('touchmove', this.handleMoveProcess);
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.handleMoveEnd);
        document.addEventListener('touchend', this.handleMoveEnd);
    };

    handleMoveProcess = e => {
        if (this.mouseMove.startedAtMS === null) {
            return;
        }
        if (getCurrentTimeMS() - this.mouseMove.startedAtMS >= LONG_CLICK_TOLERANCE_MS) {
            const clientY = getClientY(e);
            const heightChange = this.mouseMove.y - clientY;
            const newHeight = this.mouseMove.initialHeight + heightChange;
            if (document.body.clientHeight < newHeight + HEIGHT_TOLERANCE * 1.5) {
                return;
            }
            if (newHeight < HEIGHT_TOLERANCE) {
                return;
            }
            this.setState({
                height: newHeight,
                isResizing: true,
            });
        }
    };

    handleMoveEnd = e => {
        if (getCurrentTimeMS() - this.mouseMove.startedAtMS < LONG_CLICK_TOLERANCE_MS) {
            const newValue = !this.props.open;
            this.setState({
                height: newValue ? parseInt(document.body.clientHeight / 2) : HEIGHT_TOLERANCE,
                isResizing: false,
            }, () => {
                this.props.onToggle(newValue);
            });
        }
        this.mouseMove = getDefaultMouseMove();
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', this.handleMoveProcess);
        document.removeEventListener('touchmove', this.handleMoveProcess);
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.handleMoveEnd);
        document.removeEventListener('touchend', this.handleMoveEnd);
    };
```

If user presses on DOM element longer than `LONG_CLICK_TOLERANCE_MS` than `handleMoveProcess` changes height of another DOM element which must be resizable. If press duration is less than `LONG_CLICK_TOLERANCE_MS` that we think that is was a click and we resize resizable element to predefined size.

`HEIGHT_TOLERANCE = 45` is the height of handler which can be clicked/dragged by user.

Actually it is trying to implement behavior like in google maps.

1. Click to show bottom element

[image]

2. Bottom element is visible with predefined height after click action

[image]

3. We can drag this element using small gray line on top if it to change it's height

[image]

So my main problem is how to differ click and mousemove actions to handle it differently?

Comment: When you click cursor coordinates should be same for `onMouseDown` and `onMouseUp`. And different when user moved smth

Comment: I think you should somehow find out if  `mousemove` is happened between `mousedown` and `mouseup`, along with time checking to trigger resize event.

Answer (score 1):

For my project, I wanted `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` This is how I implemented [mouse-events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#mouse-events).
You can checkout [react supported-events](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#supported-events)

**Mouse Events**

> onClick onContextMenu onDoubleClick onDrag onDragEnd onDragEnter onDragExit
>   onDragLeave onDragOver onDragStart onDrop onMouseDown onMouseEnter onMouseLeave
>   onMouseMove onMouseOut onMouseOver onMouseUp

```
onMouseEnter = () => {
    this.stopTimer();
  };

  onMouseLeave = () => {
    this.startTimer();
  };

return (
      <div onMouseEnter={this.onMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave}>
        <p>Your content</p>
      </div>
    );
```

Here are quick demos [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-58639557-l9ex5) and [codepen](https://codepen.io/blueseal/pen/abbVmXg). you can observe mouse events

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion by https://stackoverflow.com/users/8163773/arseniy-ii works perfectly. Just compare coordinates in onMouseDown and onMouseUp handles and if they are different it is not a click.